# Understanding project dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have two projects:

- project A -- this one has the main code
- project B -- this one has the test code

(for some reason I have to keep test code in a separate project for a while)

Now in project B, I am adding a testCompile dependency configuration on project A. I want to understand the difference between these dependency configuration statements:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(":ProjectA")
    testCompile project(":projectA").sourceSets.main.output
    testCompile project(path: "projectA", configuration: "compile")
}
```

I am asking this question because I actually want to pull in all the compile time dependencies of project A into the testCompile dependency of project B and I can't figure out how to do that. I assumed

```
testCompile project(path: "projectA", configuration: "compile")
```

will work, but it doesn't.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In projectB's build.gradle, you can add this:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':projectA')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This tells gradle to use the main code of projectA in projectB. Then you can write tests against projectA in projectB.

You can do this to get more information about a dependency:

```
task print << {
    println project(":projectA").getClass() //Output: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
    println project(":projectA").sourceSets.main.output.getClass() //Output: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput_Decorated
    println project(path: "projectA", configuration: "compile").getClass() //This doesn't work in gradle 3.0
}
```

Both a project or a source set can be input to a configuration in the dependencies{} block